# Materializecss não está responsivo

Tags: html, html5, materialize

Há alguns dias fiz um template em materializecss; hoje acessei do celular e percebi que ele não está ficando responsivo.

Vou deixar algumas prints para esclarecer melhor:

**Responsivo (somente quando diminui o browser)**

[image: Responsivo (somente quando diminui o browser)]

**Não responsivo (quando acessado de um celular mesmo**

[image: Não responsivo (quando acessado de um celular mesmo)]

Alguém saberia me dar uma luz do porque isto está acontecendo?

Comment: Isso pode ser por que a resolução do seu celular é muito grande, então ele pega o css de alta resolução e direciona para o pc. Você pode resolver isso diminuindo o range de resolução ao qual são atribuidas as propriedades de css para celular. Acho que fui claro

Comment: @TiagoP.C O pior é que simulei todos celulares no Chrome e deu o mesmo problema. Do meu Galaxy S3 mini que tem uma tela considerada pequena também ficou assim. Se quiser dar uma olhada: https://megamund-scofield17.c9users.io/index.html

Comment: Não parece que ficou errado, parece ok.. qual  o problema?

Comment: @SCOFIELD, tente colocar isso no head do seu html: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: Pronto @GuilhermeNascimento ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque o seguinte código no head do seu HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Deve ser isto mesmo +1

Comment: Era isso mesmo @TiagoP.C eu pensei que não era necessário declarar o viewport com o materialize, me enganei. Agradecido!

Comment: Feliz em ajudar! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `media queries` para fazer ajustes em determinadas resoluções:
Ex.:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 768px){
    .h2{
        font-size: 3.0em;
    }
}
```